# Rails simple search doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I've implemented a simple search into my Rails application. Whenever I click the search, it doesn't return any results but remains the same.

I have a model `Contract`, below is the code

```
def self.search(search)
  where(["contract_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])   
end
```

In the `Contract` controller,

```
def index
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @search = params[:search]
    if @search
       @contracts = @current_user.contracts.search(@search).order("created_at DESC")
    else
       @contracts = @current_user.contracts.order('created_at DESC')
    end
end
```

In the `Contract`, `index.html.erb`,

```
<form action="<%= contracts_path%>" method ="get">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control'%>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

<% if @current_user.contracts.present? %>
<% @current_user.contracts.each do |f| %>
    <% if @current_user.contracts.present? %>
    <% @current_user.contracts.each do |f| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= f.contract_name %></td>
    <td><%= f.contract_email %></td>
    <td><%= f.contract_type %></td>
    <td><label class="label label-success" ><%= f.contract_relationship %></label></td>
    <% end %>
    <% else %>
    <td colspan="5"><center>There are currently no contracts yet.</center></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

I have another Rails app which works perfectly, I follow the exact same way of the search code, but it doesn't work in this Rails app. I have also noticed that the logs of the another project return this, which works perfectly.

```
SELECT "coworkings".* FROM "coworkings" WHERE "coworkings"."partner_id" = ? AND (title LIKE '%myspace%')  ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["partner_id", 20]]
```

While this project only return this, the other half seems like missing, weird

```
SELECT "contracts".* FROM "contracts" WHERE "contracts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 3]]
```

I follow the exact same way of another project, but it still doesn't work in this application. I'm using `SQLite3` for both of the projects. It would be appreciated if you can point out the error that I'd made.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.search` is a class method of `Contract`. But you're trying to call it on an `ActiveRecord_Rrelation`. I'm surprised that you didn't get an undefined method error.

What you want is a scope:

```
## contract.rb
scope :search, lambda { |term|
  where(["contract_name LIKE ?", "%#{term}%"])
}
```

Then you can chain it like what you did.

```
@contracts = @current_user.contracts.search(@search).order("created_at DESC")
```